# How to make the Router load a page from a different assembly based on the country the user is in

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, razor-class-library

I have an app that I would like to make country-specific such that different pages are shown based on country, for the same route.

For every country, I have an RCL that is lazy-loaded, with custom components. My goal is that when I go to `domain.com/` or `domain.com/shop`, the country-specific component will load from a Razor Class Library. This means that multiple components have the same route across RCLs.

As an example:

1. US: The router will load `domain.com/shop` from `USApp.dll`.
2. Canada: The router will load `domain.com/shop` from `CanadaApp.dll`.

The country is stored in local storage in the browser and can be changed antime.

In what ways can I achieve this? There are no docs on custom routing for this case.

Comment: Comment rather than answer as I don't have the time to create a  whole solution. Read country from local storage in `App.razor` `OnInitialized` and set the AdditionalAssemblies property of the Router component to the relevant RCL for that country.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Haha this is exactly what I did now. This is the way to go. I guess sometimes I am blind to simple solutions... I am adding this solution as an answer.

Comment: @MisterMagoo when you have time you can add your answer to the question and I will accept yours instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution is quite simple. As pointed out by @MisterMagoo you can just change the additional assemblies on the fly.

This is what I ended up with:

`App.razor`:

```
@using System.Reflection
@using Blazored.LocalStorage
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Services
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@inject LazyAssemblyLoader AssemblyLoader
@inject ILogger<App> Logger
@inject ILocalStorageService localStorageService

<CascadingValue Value="AppCountry">
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AdditionalAssemblies="@lazyLoadedAssemblies" AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true" OnNavigateAsync="@OnNavigateAsync">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
</CascadingValue>
```

`App.razor.cs`:

```cs
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class App : ComponentBase
    {
        private List<Assembly> lazyLoadedAssemblies = new();

        public string AppCountry { get; set; }

        private async Task OnNavigateAsync(NavigationContext args)
        {
            try
            {
                AppCountry = await localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("Country");
                Console.WriteLine(AppCountry);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppCountry))
                {
                    AppCountry = "RO";
                }
                IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = Enumerable.Empty<Assembly>();
                switch (await localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("Country"))
                {
                    case "RO":
                        assemblies = await AssemblyLoader.LoadAssembliesAsync(
                        new[]
                           {
                           "RomanianAppLayout.dll"
                           });

                        break;

                    case "US":
                        assemblies = await AssemblyLoader.LoadAssembliesAsync(
                        new[]
                           {
                           "USAppLayout.dll"
                           });
                        break;

                    default:
                        await localStorageService.SetItemAsync("Country", "RO");
                        goto case "RO";

                }

                lazyLoadedAssemblies.Clear();
                lazyLoadedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("Error: {Message}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's ok, leave yours as the accepted answer - no point duplicating the work.